# Sql error input parameter is int still showing conversion error

Tags: sql

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'INSERT into TheInternetOfThingsRptDB_Events
>       ( Name, Details, StartDate,EndDate,ImageUrl,URL,StartTime,
>       EndTime,Keywords,City,Country,Timezone,Sponsors,UserName,EventType,IsSponcered)
>       VALUES(Test,Test entry,01-12-2017,02-12-2017,
>       Images/EventImages/5435e988-574b-4a2a-b168-b02b5af77ea2_content-marketing-summit.jpg,
>       d7dmedia.com/Advertise/Pubsite/Signup.aspx,
>       11 AM,16 PM,Test,test,India,PST,Test,mark@deck7.io,' to data type int.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at

Comment: Check you data type in DB, and check your var conversion. If your data type in DB is INT, then your var MUST BE INT too. Check the codes and make sure all variable has converted into correct data type. Better you shared the line of error codes and your DB table data type.

Comment: I guess your some string values inside SQL should be like `'Test'`

Comment: Input parameter is integer and in sql query parameter is integer

Comment: Show us your (C#??) code and tell us which DBMS you are using ("SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a DBMS product). **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: https://snag.gy/3UMY2f.jpg

Comment: Above image is for SQL query getting error for event type

Comment: additional info: your values should have a `single quote` for the `nvarchar` type.

Comment: Yes sir but I am getting error for integer value pass integer parameter to integer variable @eventtype int

Comment: @AnkitRai base on the syntax for your sql query.. the`EventType` is the second to the last column.. as per checking your values, your second to the last value is `Test`. that's why it cannot convert to int.

Comment: It is considering input parameter as string what is wrong with stored procedure not getting that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I short the query in image Posting the actual sp again.

Comment: https://snag.gy/R8GZaA.jpg

Comment: maybe u could also post your code

Comment: @AnkitRai why do you need to build your query as nvarchar then execute it? much better to write the insert into statement directly

Comment: https://snag.gy/c82PuJ.jpg                             Code passing parameter

Comment: Sir actually this same query will use to insert data in 45 different table depending in input site.

Comment: I am generating table name on basis of site name

Comment: Tabel structure

Comment: EventID     INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 Name        NVARCHAR (500),
 Details     NVARCHAR (max),
 Location    NVARCHAR (500),
 StartDate   DATETIME,
 EndDate     DATETIME,
 StartTime   NVARCHAR (100),
 EndTime     NVARCHAR (100),
 ImageUrl    NVARCHAR (256),
 URL         NVARCHAR (256),
 EventType   INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
 Keywords    NVARCHAR (500),
 City        NVARCHAR (150),
 Country     NVARCHAR (150),
 Timezone    NVARCHAR (50),
 Sponsors    NVARCHAR (500),
 IsActive    BIT DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
 EntryDate   DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,

Comment: IsSponcered BIT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
 UserName    NVARCHAR (150),
 CONSTRAINT PK_TheInternetOfThingsRptDB_Events PRIMARY KEY (EventID)